# Zoom and paging in one ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

i am trying to create something like Photos gallery.

But now i have problem, with zooming in UIScrollView.

```
for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
    }

    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.delegate = self
```

Paging works fine, but i dont know now how to enable zooming each imageView.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the following method from the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol:

```
func viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
```

In that you return the view that you want to be zooming.

Now in this case you have multiple image views (depending on imageArray.count) but I assume you want to scroll into them all (i.e. not an individual image) so the best thing would be to add a 'content view' (UIView) to the scroll view and then add the individual image views to that instead of the scroll view directly and size it appropriately.

Then you can return that 'content view' in the `viewForZooming` method.

So assuming you have created this 'content view' then the method would look like this:

```
func viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.contentView
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'import' it?  You have assigned self as the scroll views delegate so it must be conforming to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol already.  The `viewForZooming` method is one of that's optional methods so you just need to create a method that matches it.

Comment: It said: instance method 'viewForZooming(in:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'viewForZooming(in:)' of protocol 'UIScrollViewDelegate'

Comment: If it nearly matches then you haven't quite written it write the format of the method is 'viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView) -> UIView?' so it needs to match that exactly.  There might even be an option to fix it if you tap on the error I can't remember.

Comment: Difficult to say then without seeing all the code but this tutorial shows how it works: [Scroll View Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/560-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Problem is... I cant implement this method... Or i dont know how? because when i imported UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, i dont have there this method...

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a complete example of how the method should look.  Beyond that I can't say what is wrong without looking at the rest of the code in the project to see if something else is defined incorrectly.

Comment: When i put your code in my project... It said: Instance method 'viewForZooming(in:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'viewForZooming(in:)' of protocol 'UIScrollViewDelegate'

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me.  What version of Swift are you targeting?  If it's a slightly older one the signature of the function is probably slightly different.

Comment: Version: Swift 4.2

Comment: Right technically the full definition of the method is `func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?` however my version also works fine.  Check you don't already have something like that defined because if you have both then you will get the error (or warning) you are referring to.

Comment: Clean build folder and it works... Thanks for your time!

Comment: No worries, glad to help.